# How to mock this method using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this code that I'm trying to write a unit test for but I'm not sure where to begin. This is what I've done so far:

```java
public void statusChange()
  if (this.checked && !this.boxChecked) {
     this.setBoxChecked(true);
     this.setChecked(true);
  } else if (!this.checked && this.boxChecked) {
    this.setBoxChecked(false);
    this.setChecked(false);
  }
}

...

@Mock 
@Test
public void statusChange() {
  // ...
}
```

I'm not sure what to mock or how to test the method.

Comment: It looks like a straightforward method to test. Why would you need Mockito for this? If you have access to what's referencing `this` in the class that owns `statusChange`, just check for the conditions depending on `checked` and `boxChecked`...that's all you need, unless those setters are doing something more than just setting the values.

Comment: `if (checked != boxChecked) { setBoxChecked(checked); setChecked(checked); } `

Answer (score 0):

In this case you provided using mocks doesn't make sense because you don't use any other services/dependencies inside. Using mockito make sense if your logic depends of other components.

But anyway if you want to use mockito you can try this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SomeClassMockitoTest {

  @InjectMocks
  SomeClass someClass;

  @Test
  void shouldTestSomething() {
    // given

    // when
    someClass.statusChange();

    // then
    assertSoftly(s -> {
      s.assertThat(someClass.isBoxChecked()).isFalse();
      s.assertThat(someClass.isChecked()).isFalse();
    });
  }

}

class SomeClass {

  private boolean checked;
  private boolean boxChecked;

  public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
  }

  public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
  }

  public boolean isBoxChecked() {
    return boxChecked;
  }

  public void setBoxChecked(boolean boxChecked) {
    this.boxChecked = boxChecked;
  }

  public void statusChange() {
    if (this.checked && !this.boxChecked) {
      this.setBoxChecked(true);
      this.setChecked(true);
    } else if (!this.checked && this.boxChecked) {
      this.setBoxChecked(false);
      this.setChecked(false);
    }
  }
}
```